# Why does the Key/Mouse listener detect mouse presses but not key presses? (Java awt window)

Tags: java, awt, keylistener, mouselistener, jwindow

So, my window detects mouse presses but not key presses.

Here some shortened code:

```
public class Frame {
    public static final int MAX_WIDTH = (int) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth();
    public static final int MAX_HEIGHT = (int) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight();

    private static final JWindow window = new JWindow();
    private static final DrawMain dm = new DrawMain();
    private static final GIH gih = new GIH();

    public static void init() {
        window.setSize(CVar.clientSizeX, CVar.clientSizeY);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setAutoRequestFocus(true);
        window.add(dm);
        window.addMouseListener(mh);
        window.addMouseWheelListener(mh);
        window.addMouseMotionListener(mh);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void update() {
            window.remove(dm);
            window.removeMouseListener(mh);
            window.removeMouseMotionListener(mh);
            window.removeMouseWheelListener(mh);
            window.setSize(MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT);
            window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            window.add(dm);
            window.setAutoRequestFocus(true);
            window.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
            window.addMouseListener(gih);
            window.addMouseWheelListener(gih);
            window.addMouseMotionListener(gih);
            window.addKeyListener(gih);
            window.setVisible(true);
    }
}

public class GIH implements KeyListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, MouseWheelListener {
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getKeyChar());
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        switch (e.getButton()) {
            case MouseEvent.BUTTON1 -> {
                System.out.println("Mouse 1 clicked");
            }
            case MouseEvent.BUTTON3 -> {
                System.out.println("Mouse 3 clicked");
            }
        }
    }
```

For whatever reason, i get my Mouse 1 clicked message if i click, but neither the key char if i press a key nor the output that the game would usually give on key press. Instead i write the respective character into IntelliJ (my IDE). I tried out multiple variations of window and dm.requestFocus() and window.setAutoRequestFocus(true) but none of them works. Does anyone know why? (Notice: dm is just a class with a paintComponent method)

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using [JFrame](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) with [setUndecordated(true)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated(boolean))?

Comment: Partially, i tried that and i got lots of Bugs which were fixed by replacing it with a Window. I dont know why it fixed the bugs to be honest but it was easier to fix them all that way instead of every bug alone.

Comment: A component must have focus to receive a KeyEvent. 1) Don't use a JWindow (as suggested by Gennadii) Instead use a JFrame as suggested above. 2) Don't use a KeyListener. Instead use `Key Bindings`. It will allow you handle a KeyStroke and invoke an Action even if the component doesn't have focus on your active frame. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more information. Also check out: [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I programmed the game for 5 years now (since i am twelve) and therefore had little to no knowledge about programming that time. Because the code was therefore crap i reworked it peace by peace and i got this mouse yes but no keys glitch since i reworked the GameInputHandler class a few days ago. By changing the Window to JFrame the bug was resolved and i had no random bugs appear. I bet they were there because code was a mess in the first place. ^^

Answer (score -1):

try to add window.addKeyListener(...) into init() method.

Comment: For the small example it could work. the problem is, that the game is split into client and ingame. If i add the key listener before update is called pressing keys in the client would cause a ton of exceptions since all of the code inside the key interaction methods would point to null. . .

Comment: Does your window has an owner Frame? From javadoc: "To use a JWindow component in your GUI, you should know that the JWindow component's owning frame must be visible in order for any components in the window to get the focus. By default, if you do not specify an owning frame for a JWindow component, an invisible owning frame is created for it. The result is that components in the JWindow component might not be able to get the focus.", if your window has no focus, how it recieve an event?

Comment: No it doesn't. I thought JWindow was like a JFrame with less unneccessary stuff like the Decoration. I wounder why it worked before i changed some major elements in the frame class since the comments hint it shouldn't have in the first place.